# Fusion Charts "placeValuesInside" option nor working for combination chart "MSColumn3DLineDY"

Tags: fusioncharts

My Fusion Charts version is 3.0.3 (please do not advice me to update it - this is not an option this time).

This is screenshot from my chart:

[image]

The problem is the overlapping values of the bar chart and the trend line chart. That's why I want to use the  "placeValuesInside" with value "1" to force the bar chart to show its values outside the bar.

Here are part of my options:

```
<chart placeValuesInside='0' palette='2' animation='1' formatNumberScale='0' labelDisplay='Rotate' slantLabels='1' seriesNameInToolTip='0' lineThickness='6' showValues='1' rotateValues='0' >
```

Could you advice what to do?I suppose I should point for which diagram the option to be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeValuesInside='0' will make the data values to be displayed outside the bars but this wont be applicable when the columns' roof come very near to the canvas top margin.

So, first of all, placeValuesInside='0' is the default behavior and second to use  canvasTopMargin to guarantee the option will work is not a good solution too.

I have use other option:  valuePadding='0'

The problem was that there is a default padding between value text and the end of column.